# Reading in a 6G text file, why it takes 60G memory and how to reduce it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, large-files

I have a 6G tsv file. The content of the file are numbers with the largest number being 57134205. The file is actually a lookup table with the first number on each line being the key, and the following numbers on that line being the values mapped to that key. In the form of python dict, it is like the following:

lookup[1]=[1,2,3,4]
lookup[2]=[7,8]
...

So I thought this is something trivial and tried to read in the file line by line (I am using python 3.7):

```py
R={}
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        l=list(map(int,line.split('\t')))
        R[l[0]] = set(l[1:])
```

But this blew up my machine which has 64G memory (got memory error before finishing reading the file). I suspected that it is due to the int type of the numbers so I tried keeping them as str, which amounted to changing the line

```py
l=list(map(int,l.split('\t')))
```

to

```py
l=line.split('\t')
```

This still failed and I tried to explicitly use np.uint32

```py
l=[np.uint32(i) for i in line.split('\t')]
```

Still failed.

Now I am out of ideas. I understand that the data structures would take more space than the numbers themselves, but still surprised that this 6G file cannot fit in 64G memory, unless there is some bug in the code that I completely ignored. Please let me know if there are any suggestions. Thank you for your help!

Comment: How much _free_ RAM does your machine have? Have you tried restarting the computer and running your script right away?

Comment: Also, as far as I know, dictionaries are organized in such a way that they need 1.5 times (I don't know what the exact number is) more memory than a contiguous array, so `R` might as well be trying to request, say, 2GB of space for 1GB of data.

Comment: ok, what's the purpose of using the final data structure? what are further operations?

Comment: @ForceBru, the machine has at least 54G memory available when I ran it. But I think you are right, the dict takes more than 1.5 times. And set() takes even more. I removed set and I can read in the file now, but it still takes 4 times the raw size of the file.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, the final data structure is used as a quick lookup table. Specifically, for any given i and j, I would like to know the overlap of R[i] and R[j].

Comment: @user2727768, what is `j` in your case? can you share the 1st line of the input file and search condition with a result for lookup operation on it ?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you find yourself trying to save memory while storing arrays of homogenous data, you may benefit from [the `array` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#module-array).

In your case, you should be able to put your data in a *contiguous* memory region and organize it like a singly-linked list, so that you'd be able to search it later. You'll save a lot of memory, but you'll have to trade the `O(1)` search complexity offered by dictionaries for an `O(number of loop iterations, apparently?)` one (see the `get_value_at_index` function below), offered by the linear search algorithm, which may be further optimized if you use a doubly-linked list and take into account the offset of the value from the previous search.

```
import random
import array
import sys

def write_file(fname: str, nlines: int) -> int:
    '''
    Write `nlines` lines to file `fname`.
    Return the number of entries written.
    '''
    data_range = range(57134205)
    nentries_total = 0
    with open(fname, 'w') as f:
        for x in range(nlines):
            nentries = random.randint(0, 30)
            data = random.sample(data_range, nentries)
            data.insert(0, x)
            nentries_total += nentries + 1

            data_str = ','.join(map(str, data))
            f.write(data_str + '\n')

    return nentries_total

def store_that(fname: str) -> array.array:
    result = array.array('L')
    next_index = 0
    with open(fname) as f:
        for line in f:
            index, *values = map(int, line.split(','))

            next_index += len(values) + 2
            result.append(index)
            result.append(next_index)
            result.extend(values)

    return result

def get_value_at_index(array: array.array, index: int) -> array.array:
    current_index_offset = 0
    next_index_offset = array[current_index_offset + 1]
    current_index = array[current_index_offset]

    while current_index != index:
        current_index = array[next_index_offset]
        current_index_offset = next_index_offset
        next_index_offset = array[next_index_offset + 1]

    return array[current_index_offset + 2:next_index_offset]


FNAME = 'test.txt'
number_of_keys = 2_000
total_size = write_file(FNAME, number_of_keys)
data = store_that(FNAME)

for x in range(10):
    index = random.randint(0, number_of_keys)
    value = get_value_at_index(data, index)
    print(f'data[{index}] == {value}')
print()

actual_size = data.buffer_info()[1]
size_of_object, size_of_data = sys.getsizeof(data), actual_size * data.itemsize
print(f'Key count     : {number_of_keys: >7} keys')
print(f'Element count : {total_size: >7} elements')
print(f'With indices  : {actual_size: >7} elements ({actual_size / total_size - 1:.3%} overhead)')
print(f'Size of data  : {size_of_data:_} bytes')
print(f'Size of object: {size_of_object:_} bytes    ({size_of_object / size_of_data - 1:.3%} overhead)')
print(f'\nTotal overhead: {size_of_object / (total_size * data.itemsize) - 1:.3%}')
```

With this setup, I'm getting output like this:

```
Key count     :    2000 keys
Element count :   31477 elements
With indices  :   33477 elements (6.354% overhead)
Size of data  : 133_908 bytes
Size of object: 136_808 bytes    (2.166% overhead)

Total overhead: 8.657%
```

Note that your results will vary because this code randomizes the number of entries to be stored.